# Moodle [errorcode] => errorcoursecontextnotvalid

Tags: moodle

Hi while connecting Edwise Bridge to moodle i am getting this error:

An issue is detected.
Status :
Connection Failed

URL:
https://fxcursos.entendiendoforex.com//webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=38546d8b79c6a1b150fb13b6f0e36a76&wsfunction=core_course_get_courses&moodlewsrestformat=json

Response :
stdClass Object ( [exception] => moodle_exception [errorcode] => errorcoursecontextnotvalid [message] => You cannot execute functions in the course context (course id:1). The context error message was: error/forcepasswordchangenotice )

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Edwise Bridge? Also, do you know what version of Moodle it is? https://edwiser.org/bridge/

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The problem is Force Password Change is activated. I have gone inside the user account & unchecked the Force Password Change checkbox, after performing this change I am able to test the Moodle connection. [image]